# Check type of React component

Tags: reactjs

I need to loop through component's `children` and do some things only if child component is of specific type:

```
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
    if (...) {
        console.log('Suitable component!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

this.props.children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.type === MyComponent) {
        console.log('This child is <MyComponent />');
    }
});
```

Comment: Without `name` it stops working. Currently it is surprising for me because I also think it should work.

Comment: @KonstantinSmolyanin Consider providing a way to replicate the problem in the question. If `child` is exactly an element of `MyComponent` type, it should work.

Comment: You shouldnt pass `name`. You just write ` child.type === MyComponent`. Make sure that's your component and not a string. I'm updating my answer, so you know where that MyComponent is coming

Comment: It works without name as expected. If I find what happens in my specific case I will comment here (because in my app it still doesn't work without name). I mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: I've found the problem! So strange behavior was caused by `react-hot-loader` that I use in development mode.

Comment: Relevant issue on `react-hot-loader` GitHub: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/304

Comment: This check won't check for inheritance and thus breaks inheritance model. It shouldn't be used at all (even if you don't need inheritance _right now_).

Comment: @XLII Inheritance is an anti-pattern when making components and should almost never be used. This approach seems fine to me.

Comment: Is there documentation for the 'type' property on a react element? The docs don't seem to mention it anywhere.

Comment: Has anyone else had trouble with this using Vite? I get inconsistent results -- sometimes the test works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it changes on page load or when I add a second irrelevant type test. (The `react-hot-loader` workaround doesn't change anything).

Comment: It seems it only works in development, not in the production build in React 18

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out by Konstantin Smolyanin, the accepted answer might not play nicely with react-hot-loader.

A safer alternative, suggested [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/304):

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
const myComponentType = (<MyComponent />).type;

this.props.children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.type === myComponentType ) {
        console.log('This child is <MyComponent />');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Other solution:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
// const myComponentType = (<MyComponent />).type;
// It's the same than
const myComponentType = React.createElement(MyComponent).type;

this.props.children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.type === myComponentType) {
        console.log('This child is <MyComponent />');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

My current solution is

```
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';

...


React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
    if (child.type.name === MyComponent.name) {
        console.log('Suitable component!');
    }
});
```

but I see that `type` property of React element is not documented (or I'm bad in reading documentation?). So I'm looking for more reliable solution.

**Update:**

Actually code `if (child.type.name === MyComponent.name)` should be simplified as `if (child.type === MyComponent)`. But that didn't work for me. I've found that it was caused by `react-hot-loader`. Disabling it has repaired my app.

Relevant issue on `react-hot-loader` GitHub: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/304

Comment: You likely read in a wrong place. `child` is not React *component* but *element*. Matching classes by names doesn't make sense on client-side. Most classes will be minified to something like `a` or `e`.

Comment: @estus ... yes, element, thank you for clarification. Could you provide a link to official documentation of ReactElement? I really can't find it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Comment: It isn't documented in detail because React documentation is one big guide. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement , `type` is explained there.