# How to get the name of the react component from the object property?

Tags: reactjs

i want to get the name of the reactcomponent from array of object

i have the component in the below data structure

```
const data = [ 
                 {component: <FirstComponent/>},
                 {component: <SecondComponent/>},
             ];
```

Now the question is how do i check if data[0].component is FirstComponent?

something like this data[0].component === 'FirstComponent'

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55729582/check-type-of-react-component

Comment: @oemera I think the idea is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code to match a name of a component class

```
this.data[0].component.type.name === "FirstComponent"
```

or

```
data[0].component.type.name === "FirstComponent"
```